# ID для Notifications в Android

Tags: android, android-notification

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как генерировать id для Notifications? Первое, что пришло в голову - enum с типами уведомлений и брать у него ordinal, но тогда исключается ситуация, если два одинаковых уведомления должны быть показаны одновременно

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от ваших задач. Если вам надо затирать старые уведомления новыми - устанавливайте одинаковый ID. Если не надо - разные. Разные ID можно получать по разному. В зависимости от того, насколько вы боитесь коллизий. Скорее всего вам подойдёт простейший `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Также с 7 андроида уведомления можно группировать: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group

```
val GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL"

val newMessageNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MainActivity, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
    .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSenderName())
    .setContentText(emailObject.getSubject())
    .setLargeIcon(emailObject.getSenderAvatar())
    .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
    .build()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]